# Node.js Garbage Collection Behavior

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks

I am wondering when the Node.js garbage collector should run to reclaim unused memory?  I have a very simple Node.js program that makes a POST request once every second using the https module.  This code seems to eat up a good chunk of memory over a pretty short period of time.  Also the memory usage never seems to go down like I would expect.  I don't think I have a memory leak here, although I could...
I am just wondering when the garabage collector should run?  Does is not run until it reaches a certain memory limit?  If so what is that limit?

Right now I am running my Node app in a PaaS environment that only has 128MB and I quickly run out of memory.  I can give it more memory but I want to know if that will solve the problem or if it will just prolong the time before I run out of memory again.

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  hostname: 'user.cloudant.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/mem',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: "user:pass",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  }
};
var data = JSON.stringify({"hello" : "world"});
setInterval(function() {
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });
  req.write(data);
  req.end();

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Here is a sample memory graph, the first drop at 4:47PM is because I restarted the app.
[image]

Comment: What node version? Also did you compare it to only making another request once the previous one had finished, instead of using setInterval()?

Comment: I am using 0.10.31.  I have not tried waiting until the first request finished because in my actual application that is not how it will work.  In my real application I am getting data published over MQTT and making the POST request.  That data can come very frequently and the previous requests may have not completed before making another request.